# Query custom posts of logged in user only

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts

I have a custom post type setup called `website` I thought using the code below would display only the logged in users posts but it's displaying all of the custom posts even those not belonging to the logged in user. Can someone show me what the query is to get only the custom posts by the logged in user

```
global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();
$authorID = $current_user->ID;
    $args = array(
              'post_type' => 'post',//or whatever you need
              'posts_per_page' => 5,
              'author' => $authorID
              );

    $temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query= null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a small plugin to add your custom post type to the default loop, if the user is logged in.

```
// add custom post type to wp loop
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fb_add_to_query' );

// ads to query
function fb_add_to_query( $query ) {

    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) // if user not logged in, return
        return $query;

    if ( is_admin() || is_preview() ) // return, if in backend or preview
        return $query;

    if ( ! isset( $query -> query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) )
        $query -> query_vars['suppress_filters'] = FALSE;

    // conditional tags for restrictions
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() && ( FALSE == $query -> query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) 
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'my_post_type' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: This isn't for the home page though, it's in a custom page template.

Comment: You must change the conditional tags for restrictions and ready, then works only on your page tamplate.

Comment: I tried setting it to this ` if ( is_page() && ( FALSE == $query -> query_vars['suppress_filters'] ) ) ` but it doesn't display any posts at all.

Comment: Is this to go into functions.php or in my page template? If in functions.php what is the code to play into my page template? Thanks

Comment: Use as plugin or functions.php.

Comment: I placed that into my functions.php and changed is_home() to is_page() and I get a 404 when i refresh my page.

Comment: do you have change the string for your custom post type from the example 'my_post_type'?